# Embed flash in html

Tags: html, flash, embed

In chrome, ie and safari this is not a problem, but in firefox it is.

I use `<object>` for my flashclip.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"> 
    <param name="movie" value="myclip.swf" /> 
    <param name="quality" value="high" /> 
</object>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some testing, this works fine:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="myclip.swf" 
    width="550" height="400"> 

    <param name="movie" value="myclip.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
</object>
```

Firefox needed both `data`, `width` and `height`.

Comment: Yes, `embed` is deprecated and not necessary in modern browsers (not even IE6 IIRC). It's a pain to find the right combination of attributes though. I can never remember the right ones.

Answer (score 12):

For cross browser flash embedding, you need to use **both** `<object>` and `<embed>` tags, nested inside one another, and it might also help to include the `data` attribute on the `<object>` like this:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="myclip.swf"> 
    <param name="movie" value="myclip.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <!-- Sandwich the embed tag inside the object tag -->
    <embed src="myclip.swf" quality="high" />
</object>
```

Alternatively, I'd suggest using the [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) javascript micro-library for robust cross browser flash embedding.

Answer (score 0):

Use both object and embed tag. Some browsers use the  tag and 'name' to get to the swf, others use  and 'id'

Comment: then does this mean <embed src="myclip.swf" width="550" height="400" /> works in more situations than object ?

Comment: embed should work...I'm guessing you knew you should set src, not movie.

Comment: also, why not use the generated html from flash, or swfobject ?

Answer (score -1):

The code is `<embed src="helloworld.swf">`.