# SWFObject based Flash movie won't show in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, swfobject

I am using Roy Tanck's WP-Cumulus Tag Cloud viewer.  It's an SWF file that is used with SWFObject.js to show a spinning sphere of tags.  It works fine in Chrome and FireFox, but in Internet Explorer 10 the canvas is blank.  If I right-click on the canvas I do see the attribution link to Roy Tanck's web site indicating the movie was loaded, and there are no errors showing in the Debugger's Console tab, but no sphere of tags, just a blank white canvas.  I am using SWFObject v2.2 and my Flash player version is 11.8.800.175.  I traced my main function (shown below) for creating the tag XML for the SWF and everything checks out fine.  Unfortunately, I get nothing but a blank display for the movie and no errors in the console.  I did look at the values for the flashvars and they are identical to what they are when I trace the method in Chrome and FireFox.  Can anyone give me some things to try that might help fix this problem?:

```
// Create the tag cloud using the given associative array where the Key is the
//  value to display in the tag cloud and the Value is the HREF for the link
//  to be associated with the display value.
function createTagCloud(aryDisplayStringsWithLinks, style)
{
    if (typeof aryDisplayStringsWithLinks == 'undefined')
        return;

    // Build tags XML partial for use by the Cumulus Tag Cloud.
    var tagCloudXML = "<tags>";

    var iCount = 0;

    for (var Key in aryDisplayStringsWithLinks)
    {
        tagCloudXML += createOneTagCloudXMLElement(Key, aryDisplayStringsWithLinks[Key], style);
        iCount++;
    } // for()

    tagCloudXML += "</tags>";

    // Must have at least two elements or the tag cloud won't make any sense.
    if (iCount < 2)
        return;

    var params =
    {
        wmode: "transparent"
    };

    var flashvars =
    {
        // TAGS HYPERLINKS ***MUST** HAVE THE STYLE ATTRIBUTE OR YOU WON'T SEE ANYTHING IN THE VIEWPORT! (and you
        //  will think it is broken when it is not).
        tagcloud: tagCloudXML,
        // tagcloud: '<tags><a href="http://google.com/" style="font-size:9pt;" >One</a><a href="http://microsoft.com/"  style="font-size:9pt;" >Two</a></tags>',

        mode: "tags",
        distr: "true",
        tcolor: "0x3366CC",
        hicolor: "0x0000bb"
    };

    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "/Content/flash/tagcloud.swf",
        "flashcontent",
        "470",
        "380",
        "9.0.0",
        "",
        flashvars
        );
} // function createTagCloud(aryDisplayStringsWithLins) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you facing the problem on 
OS: windows 8
Browser: Internet Explorer 10

- open the debugger (F12)
- Cache (menu bar) -> select ["Always refresh from server"]

It will work now.

The problem exist when all request are not 200
Debugging further to find the fix without the above tweak

Found this check if it fixes the issue for you 
[Flash not working on Windows 8 / Internet explorer 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873578/flash-not-working-on-windows-8-internet-explorer-10?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks I tried your suggestion but that did not fix it.  Note, as I said in my post the Flash player does run.  I can see the white initial Flash canvas and right-clicking over it shows the Flash context help menu.  But the area remains blank without the movie showing.  I also tried the meta tag suggested in the linked document in your reply and that did not change anything either.