# Trouble embedding flash in HTML using object tag/swfobject

Tags: html, flash, embed, swfobject

I am pulling my hair out trying to embed a flash file I have in a page, and have tried many variations of the following two ways:

*swfobject*

```
<head>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'swfobject.js' %>
</head>
.
.
.
<div id="dragndrop">This requires Adobe Flash to view</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var flashvars;
  var params = {
    movie: "<%= asset_path('flash/drag-n-drop-w-action3b.swf') %>",
    background: "#FFFFFF",
    quality: "high"
  };

  swfobject.embedSWF("<%= asset_path('flash/drag-n-drop-w-action3b.swf') %>",
    "dragndrop", "100%", "100%", "6.0.0", false, params);
</script>
```

Navigating to the page yields nothing, but outputs the following in browser:

```
<object id="dragndrop" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"       
    data="/assets/flash/drag-n-drop-w-action3b.swf" style="visibility: visible;">
  <param name="flashvars" value="movie=/assets/flash/drag-n-drop-w-action3b.swf&background=#FFFFFF&quality=high">
</object>
```

I have tried it without the params, also, to no avail.

I have also tried manually adding it in several ways including as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333202/embed-flash-in-html).  This flash file is currently embedded on a different website successfully, and I have even copy-pasted the html there (fixing the path):

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" align="" 
    codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" 
    classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
  <param value="assets/flash/drag-n-drop-w-action3b.swf" name="movie">
  <param value="high" name="quality">
  <param value="#FFFFFF" name="bgcolor">
  <embed width="100%" height="100%" align="" 
    pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" quality="high"    
    src="/assets/flash/drag-n-drop-w-action3b.swf">
</object>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Following pipwerks help, I changed the code to:

```
var params = { background: "#FFFFFF",};
swfobject.embedSWF("<%= asset_path('flash/drag-n-drop-w-action3b.swf') %>", "dragndrop", "100%", "100%", "6.0.0", false, false, params);
```

However, it is still not quite working.  The new HTML that is outputted is as follows:

```
<object id="dragndrop" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    data="/assets/flash/drag-n-drop-w-action3b.swf" style="visibility: visible;">
  <param name="background" value="#FFFFFF">
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you're accidentally passing the parameters as flashvars.

Secondly, you don't need to pass most of those parameters, as they're already taken care of. The `movie` param is the first argument in SWFObject. `quality=high` is the default for Flash Player and doesn't need to be specified. I believe `#FFFFFF` is also the default background color, but it wouldn't hurt to specify it.

The correct order of arguments is:

```
swfobject.embedSWF([swf file], 
                   [document element id], 
                   [width], 
                   [height], 
                   [min Flash Player version], 
                   [express install swf or false], 
                   [flashvars obj or false], 
                   [params obj or false], 
                   [attributes obj or false], 
                   [callback function or false]);
```

Therefore your code should be:

```
var params = { background: "#FFFFFF",};
swfobject.embedSWF("<%= asset_path('flash/drag-n-drop-w-action3b.swf') %>", "dragndrop", "100%", "100%", "6.0.0", false, false, params);
```

See [this page](http://learnswfobject.com/the-basics/advanced-options-with-dynamic-publishing/) for more details about swfobject arguments.

Comment: That solved the passing params as flash vars issue, but the flash object is still not being embedded.  Do I need to explicitly embed it?  I thought this was not necessary?  I have updated my original posted with the HTML output, using the code you provided.  Thanks for helping out; I appreciate it!